# "Microsoft Error Reporting" on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, macos-sierra

I got a Mac recently and installed Microsoft Office through my University. It was all okay. After a few days, I noticed that Excel didn't open. I got a "Microsoft Error Reporting" every time I tried to open it.

Window message: Microsoft Word has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

I came across this link, [MS KB : Office 2016 for Mac, macOS Sierra potential crash issues](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-for-Mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3)  and tried doing whatever was mentioned. It still didn't open. Next, I uninstalled all Microsoft Office products, following [MS KB : Uninstall Office 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-for-Mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3).

I installed Microsoft Office again and now, none of the applications are opening. I get the same window  when I try to open any of the softwares. Please tell me what to do and if you need more information to help solve this issue.

Comment: I can't add links.....not enough reputation...

Comment: I inlined the links for you - hope someone has a good answer for you. Earlier comment now deleted.